# Which OnyX setting resets my Chrome extensions?

Tags: google-chrome, macos

I use OnyX to clear out caches and delete superfluous files to try to make my Mac run faster. I usually just run "Automation" with the default boxes checked.

However, after I do this, I find my Chrome extensions are reset. I have to log back in to Readability, Pocket, etc.

Which OnyX checkbox do I uncheck to prevent this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the Web Browser Cache and History.  In the automated section, this setting clears for ALL web browsers and their cache.  Deselect the setting.  You can always delete your history and other browser specific caches manually thereafter.

[image: Setting to deselect]